# Sending pfx certificate in angular $http call

Tags: angularjs, http, ssl-certificate

I have an external API that I'm using: `https://example.com/`. When browsing to this, I get a popup that asks for a certificate, which I have as a .pfx file (or in my keychain as a .cer). I accept that they access the certificate and sign it with my private key and voilà - I can access the page.

Now what I want to be able to do is do this in AngularJS. What I have tried so far is:

```
$http.get("https://example.com/");
```

Response:

`Failed to load resource: The server ”...” did not accept the certificate.` - I translated this from another language, just so you know.

What I want to do is to somehow send the .pfx file in the $http request. How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by doing it in node.js instead, where there are options for certificates. I used `pfx` and `passphrase` and that was it. I however don't know if this is possible to do in AngularJS.